# APC using mod_fastcgi only caching apc.php

Tags: mod-fastcgi, alternative-php-cache

I'm on Debian 6.06, using Plesk 11.09, with Apache2 and nginx as reverse proxy.

I'm trying to setup the APC, but it seems not to work properly.
The APC Webinteface, apc.php, tells me, that APC is only caching apc.php.

I managed to get fastcgi working via mod_fastcgi and limited it to only start one master(?)
process: -maxClassProcesses 1

> [Tue Dec 11 12:25:46 2012] [notice] FastCGI: wrapper mechanism enabled (wrapper: /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper)
>
> [Tue Dec 11 12:25:46 2012] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 16352)

But every time I browse to an other .php file, fastcgi seems to spawn a new process:

> [Tue Dec 11 12:56:58 2012] [warn] FastCGI: scheduled the start of the last (dynamic) server "/var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/config/set_adress.php" process: reached dynamicMaxClassProcs (1)
> [Tue Dec 11 12:57:52 2012] [warn] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/config/verl.php" (uid 10000, gid 1005) started (pid 17032)

I guess that's why APC does only cache itself, but I don't knwo how to solve this,

I hope you can help me here!
Thanks in advance, Twain